# VirtualBox with bridged adapter on win7 cannot connect to internet

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have installed win7 on virtual box with network configuration as bridged adapter. My host machine is macbook Air with OS X 10.8.2.

This is the host's TCP/IP configuration:
[image: this is the host's TCP/IP configuration]
[image]

This is network connection details of my virtual machine:
[image: This is network connection details of my virtual machine]

I can ping any computer on my LAN from vbox. Also I can ping vbox from any computer on my LAN. But my vbox does not have Internet access. When I switch to NAT in vbox's network settings the internet access appears.
I wonder, why vbox doesn't have Internet access while configured as bridged adapter. Also, everything works on my friend's wifi LAN. I wonder, why it doesn't work in my house. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like there is nothing wrong in your Virtualbox settings (because you can get to the LAN machines), but your gateway or firewall is blocking the virtual machine traffic.

Comment: im using xfinity router. couldn't find in its settings anything that might block my vbox. however, when i set my vbox as DMZ it works fine

Comment: Is there any specific reason for preferring bridged adapter over NAT?

Comment: Bridging a Wi-Fi adapter is problematic to say the least - there are lots of questions on the various Stack Exchange sites that go over (and over, and over) this. Do you have a wired ethernet connection available? If not, a NAT connection type for your guest and port forwarding will be the next best choice: http://serverfault.com/questions/421719/virtualbox-view-guest-port-80-on-host-port-80/